# Should I convert to network byte order (hton*) if all machines on the network use little-endian?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am writing a client-server application that uses UDP to send datagrams between two Intel x64 computers. I control the hardware on both sides and have verified that they use identical little-endian architecture.

As I can confirm both machines are little-endian, are there any benefits given by using `hton*` functions to change the byte order before sending my data? Surely this creates a very slight performance decrease and gives no benefit?

Comment: An endian fixup cannot possibly be a performance bottlekneck in an application pumping data over a wire. This is [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) taken to another level. I can think of NO reason not to use hton in the very context it was made for. If you're talking about *your* data, not the lib api arguments, you could get away with it, but unless you measured and can *prove* this is a serious concern, why bother.

Comment: The problem with not using hton is that it makes your code less portable to other systems.   I actually work in a place where a predecessor made the assumption that some code would always use big endian, and that the code was only going to be used for a specific purpose -- neither of which are true anymore, and now we're paying a heavy price for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your protocol could always be used in ways you don't expect.  The program may get picked up by someone running on an ARM or Sun system, for example.

Since values sent over a network are generally expected to be in network byte order, it's best to convert your values before sending.  Any effect on performance would be negligible and would be considered premature optimization.